# jQuery pass $this to function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have:

```
<img id="leftBubble" class="bubbles" src="left.png" />
<img id="rightBubble" class="bubbles" src="right.png" />
```

And a hover event like so:

```
$(".bubbles").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function() { 
        pause($(this));
    }, function() {
        play(4000, $(this));
    });
});
```

My pause() function does not seem to be working

```
function pause(pauseMe) {
    if (pauseMe == $("#leftBubble")) {
        clearTimeout(timer1);                        //this is never reached
    } else if (pauseMe == $("#rightBubble")) {
        clearTimeout(timer2);                        //nor this
    }
}
```

Any idea to make the hover event pass $this as the parameter for the pause function?

Comment: jquery equality is best done with `.is("selector")`: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448291/how-to-check-for-dom-equality-with-jquery/2448362#2448362

Comment: compare jquery object :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436966/how-would-you-compare-jquery-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you call `$`, it returns a different result set object, even if the result contents are the same. The check you have to do is:

```
if (pauseMe.is("#leftBubble")) {
```

Answer (score 4):

Try like below,

```
function pause(pauseMe) {
    if (pauseMe == "leftBubble") {
        clearTimeout(timer1);
    } else if (pauseMe == "rightBubble") {
        clearTimeout(timer2);
    }
}
```

and in the caller,

```
$(".bubbles").each(function(){
  $(this).hover(function() { 
    pause(this.id);
  }, function() {
    play(4000, $(this));
  });
});
```

Comment: This makes the most sense. Using `.is()` seems to be overkill here.

Comment: Actually I require the object itself as the parameter, not the Id

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `this` is redefined each time you enter a new function definition. If you want to access the *outside* `this`, you need to keep a reference to it in a variable (I used the `self`) variable.

```
$(".bubbles").each(function(){
    var self = this;
    $(this).hover(function() { 
        pause($(self));
    }, function() {
        play(4000, $(self));
    });
});
```

I don't know if your comparison between jQuery objects will work though. Maybe you can compare the DOM elements: `pauseMe[0] == $("#leftBubble")[0]`, or, as mentioned, the ids.

Comment: In this case the outside `this` and the inside `this` will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$( ... )` it generates new object that not the same that was genereted when you call `$( ... )` last time, with same parametrs.

Anyway, you can't compare objects with `==` in javascript. It returns `true` only if it liks on same object.

```
a = {b:1}
c = {b:1}
d = c

a == b // false
d == c // true
```