# How to add an if statement to a toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following code, which toggles visibility of two classes with separate click() functions:

```
<!-- Toggles -->
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>

<!-- Result -->
<div class="x" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="y" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="z" style="display:none"></div>

<!-- Script -->
$( ".a" ).click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
  $this.siblings(".x").toggle();
});


$( ".b" ).click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
  $this.siblings(".y").toggle();
});
```

How would I update this so that any time both x and y are visible, a third class, "z" is shown instead of both x and y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as show here: http://jsfiddle.net/DKRe2/1/

HTML:

```
<!-- Toggles -->
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<!-- Result -->
<div class="x" style="display:none">class x</div>
<div class="y" style="display:none">class y</div>
<div class="z" style="display:none">class z</div>
```

JS:

```
<!-- Script -->
$(".a").click(function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.siblings(".y").css('display') != 'none' && $this.siblings(".x").css('display') == 'none') {
        //now Hide y and show Z  
        $this.siblings(".y").toggle();
        $this.siblings(".z").toggle();
    } else {
        $this.siblings(".z").css('display', 'none');
        $this.siblings(".x").toggle();
    }
});


$(".b").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.siblings(".x").css('display') != 'none' && $this.siblings(".y").css('display') == 'none') {
        //now Hide y and show Z   
        $this.siblings(".x").toggle();
        $this.siblings(".z").toggle();
    } else {
        $this.siblings(".z").css('display', 'none')
        $this.siblings(".y").toggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how would this work if I wanted to keep the code relational (i.e. by reference to sibilings), so only siblings were affected (classes are repeated elsewhere on the page)?

Comment: Just add back the siblings selector from before.  I removed it as it wasn't strictly necessary in the code example you gave.  I will amend answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Yn3L2/

- API `is(':visible')` http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Rest should fit your needs `:)`

**Code**

```
$(".a").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings(".x").toggle();
    checkZ();
});

$(".b").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings(".y").toggle();
    checkZ();
});

function checkZ() {
    $('.z').hide();
    if ($('.x').is(':visible') && $('.y').is(':visible')) {

        $('.z').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tats_innit thanks, if I want to keep this relational to the $this var (i.e. be able to use this multiple times on the same page, but only trigger the function on sibling classes, would  if  ($this.siblings(".a").is(':visible') && () $this.siblings(".b").is(':visible')) work?

Comment: @alias51 yeah sure you can `:)` pass `this` as a function parameter, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198768/jquery-pass-this-to-function-parameter **please note** you need to know the visibility status of both `x` and `y` at all time though! **please see this demo** http://jsfiddle.net/VxwUR/ *passing value as parameter*

Comment: @Tats_innit, thanks, I'm having difficulty following how to pass this as a function parameter; I am using checkZ($this) but still get an uncaught reference error?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you really want.

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XAQRu/1/)

Added jQuery code

```
function checkZ() {
    $('.z').hide();
    if ($('.x').is(':visible') && $('.y').is(':visible')) {
        $('.x').hide(500);
        $('.y').hide(500)
        $('.z').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would this work if I wanted to keep the code relational (i.e. by reference to sibilings), so only siblings were affected (classes are repeated elsewhere on the page)?

Comment: BY probably providing a unique Id to the child div and referecing the ID in the jQuery