# How do I compare two jQuery objects for identity?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to open / close control 'boxes' on a webpage.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look very good to close a box just to re-open it if the user happens to click on the already opened box.  (Boxes are mutually exclusive).

The code I'm using doesn't work, and I'm not sure why.  I still get a box closing just to open up anew, which isn't the desired functionality.  I created the 'val' variable for debugging purposes; in the debugger, it shows 'val' as having the exact same value as $(this), which should prevent it from getting to the `.slideToggle()` inside the if statement, but doesn't.

```
function openBox(index)
{
  val = $('#box' + index);
  $('.profilePageContentBox').each(function(){
      if($(this).css('display') != 'none')
      {
        if($(this) != val)
        {
          $(this).slideToggle(200);
        }
      }
    });
  val.slideToggle(200);
}
```

Comment: You might want to also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436966/how-would-you-compare-jquery-objects

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using the `$()` function will always create a new object, so no matter what, your equality check there will always fail.

For example:

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');

$(div) === $(div);   // false!
```

Instead, you could try just storing the actual DOM elements, since those are just *referred* to inside jQuery objects.

```
val = $('#box'+index).get(0);
...
if (this !== val) { }
```

Comment: Thanks!  As soon as StackOverflow lets me I'll accept this answer.  Not only did you answer the question itself, you also explained the conceptual flaw that was screwing me up -- 'give a man a fish, teach a man to fish'

Comment: this guy taught you how to fish with a fishing pole (lame), the bottom answer teaches you how to fish with your bare hands (BA)!

Answer (score 87):

You can also do:

```
 if(val.is(this))
```

Comment: Simple and straight forward. Great answer

Comment: best answer here. kudos!

Comment: The Object.is() method determines whether two values are the same value, this is the correct answer and this is how you fish with your bare hands :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function openBox(index)
{
val=$('#box'+index);
$('.profilePageContentBox').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":visible"))
    {
        if(!$(this).is("#box"+index))
            $(this).slideToggle(200);
    }
});
val.slideToggle(200);
}
```