# How do i compare objects using # sign in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, comparison, comparison-operators

I m using a function hitTest(a,b); i give 2 objects to it. The objects correspond to some div elements with IDs on my webpage.

where the function is called:

```
if (hitTest($('#drawer'),$('#hit'+i)))

 {
  //do something...

}
```

This is the function itself

```
function hitTest(a, b) {
    if( $(b) == $('#hit5')   ){
        console.log("hit 5");
    }
    else if( $(b) == $('#hit4')   ){
        console.log("hit 4");
    }

    else if( $(b) == $('#hit6')   ){
        console.log("hit 6");
    }
```

The problem is that **none of the if** clauses work! How do I compare 2 objects, or their types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following one:

```
function hitTest(a, b) {
    if( $(b)[0] === $('#hit5')[0]   ){
        console.log("hit 5");
    }
    else if( $(b)[0] === $('#hit4')[0]   ){
        console.log("hit 4");
    }

    else if( $(b)[0] === $('#hit6')[0]   ){
        console.log("hit 6");
    }
```

> The jQuery objects themselves are always separate objects so you have
>   to look at the contents of the actual DOM array inside each jQuery
>   object.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475132/1029506

Answer (score 2):

```js
if( $(b).is($('#hit5'))   ){
        console.log("hit 5");
    }
```

in jquery we have .is method , I think it will helps you

Comment: .is comes from jquery? so i have to have jquery plugged in my code to use ".is" ?

Comment: yes , you can use .is, because you are using jquery plugin

Comment: You are already using jquery in your code snippet as it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to compare elements? Could you just compare the selectors instead?

```
if (hitTest('#drawer', '#hit'+i))

 {
  //do something...

}



function hitTest(a, b) {
    if( b === '#hit5') {
        console.log("hit 5");
    }
    else if( b === '#hit4') {
        console.log("hit 4");
    }
    else if( b === '#hit6') {
        console.log("hit 6");
    }
}
```