# How do I check if 2 jQuery selectors are pointing to the same element(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, equality

If I try something such as this:

```
$(".foo") === $(".foo") // = false
```

... I get false. If I instead try this query,

```
$(".foo").get(0) === $(".foo").get(0) // = true
```

... I get true.

That's because:

```
{a:myObject} !== {a:myObject};
[myObject]   !== [myObject];
myObject     === myObject;
```

I'm wondering if there is any succinct way to test for this equality, preferably built into jQuery. The 2nd method I wrote only works correctly if there is at most one element which matches `.foo`. The solution should work for any amount of elements.

Obviously I don't want to just check `".foo" === ".foo"` since the actual selections I'm using are more complicated. I just simplified them for this example. (E.g. I may want to check that `$(this)` is selecting the same thing as `$(".foo")`.)

Comment: You should check out benekastah's answer, here's a demo that reflects his answer: http://jsfiddle.net/kAv4X/

Comment: @lolwut: that doesn't work since `is()` only checks that *at least one* of the elements matches the other selector (i.e. it's a subset). Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/dYAH3/ (it should say false in the first alert, but it says true).

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3856290/989121) appears to be the most accurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing in the core library to check sequence equality of jQuery objects, however the following should do the trick:

```
$.fn.sequenceEqual = function(compareTo) {
  if (!compareTo || !compareTo.length || this.length !== compareTo.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0, length = this.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (this[i] !== compareTo[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Which would be useable like so:

```
$(".foo").sequenceEqual($(".bar"))
```

For completeness, a contents equal method could be written like so:

```
$.fn.contentsEqual = function(compareTo) {
  return compareTo && this.length === compareTo.length && this.length === this.filter(compareTo).length;
}
```

Which would be useable like so:

```
$(".foo").contentsEqual($(".bar"))
```

Answer (score 14):

I think you are looking for `$().is`. [Docs here](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
var foo, bar;

foo = $('foo');
bar = $('.bar');

// This will check to see foo and bar contain the same elements
foo.is(bar); // true | false
```

**Edit**: @lolwut provided a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAv4X/2/) for this answer. After reading the comments, I updated it and determined that this answer isn't reliable for the OP's case.

Comment: @lolwut, nope, `is()` will return `true` if *at least one of the elements matches the given arguments*.

Comment: Take a look at [T.J. Crowder's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400500/how-do-i-check-if-2-jquery-selectors-are-pointing-to-the-same-elements/9401119#comment11878467_9400543) for an explanation as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: Added jsfiddle and showed how my answer is wrong. Thanks @FrédéricHamidi for explaining the problem.

Comment: This answer is correct when you're sure both objects contain **at most one element**.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check whether both sets contain *exactly* the same elements (possibly in a different order), then `Array#every` in combination with `$.fn.index` could do the job:

```
var $this  = $("p"),
    $other = $("p");


// same length and $other contains each element of $this

var equal = $this.length === $other.length
              && Array.prototype.every.call($this, function(elem) {
                   return $other.index(elem) > -1;
                 });
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to pimvdb's answer (which is very nice, I'm only providing this for completeness), you can leverage the fact that [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) will not add elements that are already present in the jQuery object. Therefore, you can write:

```
$.fn.containsSameElements = function(other) {
    var len = this.length;
    return other.length == len && this.add(other).length == len;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, using only jquery builtins, this seems to be the right one

```
$(oneSelector).filter($(anotherSelector)).length == 1
```

<s>if ($(oneSelector).is($(anotherSelector)))... they are equal</s>

Comment: No. From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/is/): *"Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if **at least one** of these elements matches the given arguments."* (my emphasis).

Comment: Your updated answer with `filter` still isn't right, although it's a big step forward. You'd need to check `length` against the length of the original set of matched elements, not `1`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: as long as they compare one single element (see the question), that's fine. Anyways, filter() is the correct way, this is how jQuery implements is() internally.

Comment: `@thg435`: Yes, look at the question: *"The 2nd method I wrote only works correctly if there is at most one element which matches `.foo`."* Clearly the OP wants a solution that **isn't** just for one element.