# Jquery comparing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array on javascript and i insert the elements on it like this:

```
 var parentRow = $(button).parent().parent();
 list.push({ parent: parentRow, detailRow: newRow });
```

On the click of another button i do the following:

```
      var parentRow = $(button).parent().parent();
      var detailRow = null;

      for (var i in list) {
        if ($(list[i].parent) == $(parentRow)) {
          detailRow = list[i].detailRow;
        }
      }
```

The point is: The if comparing to two elements should return TRUE, because they are the same DOM element....the same i added before, but it return FALSE.

I would like to know how i compare this two elements to get TRUE there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436966/how-would-you-compare-jquery-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the native elements, not the jQuery-wrapped elements. jQuery's DOM methods returns not the elements themselves but a jQuery object.

```
if (list[i].parent[0] === parentRow[0]) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (parentRow.has(list[i])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same objects, because they don't refer to the same jQuery instance.

Simple solution: Don't use jQuery and do it with normal DOM methods.

jQuery solution: Use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)