# Comparing elements on .each()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement an accordion. I'm having a problem with comparing an element in the .each() loop.

I start by finding the `.accordion` who's `.content` I need to expand. This is the parent of the `.accordion .title` element that was click (line 6 below).

I then loop through each `.accordion` on the page. I try to detect which of those `.accordion` is the `parent`, to expand his `.content`. This isn't working.

```
// ACCORDION
var accordions = $('.accordion').toArray();

// Scroll down on click
$('.accordion .title').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();


    $(accordions).each(function() {

        // Show this accordion if it's the parent of the .title clicked
        // Problem is here ********
        if ( $(this) == parent )
            $(this).children('.content').slideDown();

        // Hide all accordions except this parent
        else {
            $(this).children('.content').slideUp();
        }

    });

});
```

My main question is a bit wider than this particular example:

**How can I figure out if `$(this) == some_var_pointing_to_an_element` when looping through an array of elements like above?**

EDIT: My accordion html if it's relevant:

```
<div class=".accordion">
    <div class=".title">Hello</div>
    <div class=".content">World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `var parent = this.parentNode;` and then `if (this == parent) { ... }`.

Comment: Though I don't recommend it in this situation, you can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436966/how-would-you-compare-jquery-objects) on how to compare elements in jquery objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object comparison in JavaScript only works if both are the same instance (i.e. same memory location), but each time you use the `$()` constructor it will create a new instance.

That said, you can simplify the code somewhat by making jQuery do the looping work for you:

```
// ACCORDION
var $accordions = $('.accordion');

// Scroll down on click
$accordions.find('.title').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    $accordions
      .not($parent) // all but this one
      .children('.content');
      .slideUp();

    $parent.children('.content').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: You'll only want to slide the `.content`.  As-is, you will toggle the clickable title as well.

Comment: I'll give you the point for the added explanation at the top!

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to loop at all.  Just do this:

```
// hide the others
$(accordions).not(parent).children(".content").slideUp();

// show this one
parent.children(".content").slideDown();
```

Comment: Up-voted, though I'd maybe suggest `slideToggle()` for the last line (if the OP wants to be able to close the accordion, for example).